# Meaning of integral

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

I was reading Rudin's book on functional analysis, the chapter on distributions, the section on convolutions.
In one of the proofs, he mentions a  " $D_K$ - valued integral " where $D_K$  is the space of all infinitely differentiable functions with support in the compact set K? I wanted to know what the term " $D_K $ valued integral meant??

Comment: Earlier in the book he's explained what an $X$-valued integral is, if $X$ is a Banach space. Look in the index and table of contents for "vector-valued integrals".

Comment: It's a Frechet space valued integral rather than Banach.

Comment: Ok thank you! Initially I thought that vector valued integration had to be used but I wasn't sure and wanted to confirm